# How to display an array range via a pointer in the IAR IDE Watch window?

Tags: c, debugging, embedded, watch, iar

In the IAR Embedded Workbench I have a pointer pointing to a buffer in memory. When watching the pointer, I can see the contents of the word it points to. How can I tell the Watch view to list a range of the buffer, from the pointer onwards, for some specified length of elements?

For example, enter the expression:

```
myPtr[0..2]
```

will display information equivalent to the three expressions:

```
myPtr[0]
myPtr[1]
myPtr[2]
```

Comment: Nice idea, but I have never come across a debugger that supports interpretation of a pointer as an array of user specified length.  In these situations I generally use a memory window, but that is good only for very simple cases.

Comment: @Clifford - I am 99.99% sure you're able to do this with MS Visual Studio. Certainly it could be done with past versions.

Comment: One can do it in literally every debugger. IAR is the first I've seen which lacks the function.

Comment: @Clifford - In MSVS the way to do this is use `arrptr + offset, length` to display values from `arrptr[offset]` to `arrptr[offset+length-1]`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the Iar Embedded Workbench (9.20) help:

> In windows where you can edit the Expression field and in the Quick
>   Watch window, you can specify the number of elements to be displayed
>   in the field by adding a semicolon followed by an integer. For
>   example, to display only the three first elements of an array named
>   `myArray`, or three elements in sequence starting with the element
>   pointed to by a pointer, write:
>
> ```
> myArray;3
> ```
>
> To display three elements pointed to by `myPtr`, `myPtr+1`, and
>   `myPtr+2`, write:
>
> ```
> myPtr;3
> ```
>
> Optionally, add a comma and another integer that specifies which
>   element to start with. For example, to display elements 10–14, write:
>
> ```
> myArray;5,10
> ```
>
> To display `myPtr+10`, `myPtr+11`, `myPtr+12`, `myPtr+13`, and
>   `myPtr+14`, write:
>
> ```
> myPtr;5,10
> ```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative would be to view it in memory.  Select View -> Memory and enter the pointer value (with 0x prefix).  You can view and edit the range of data.  Maybe not as "clean" as a traditional debugger variable viewer but it does the job.